# unified import in javascript for node and the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, parceljs

In javascript that I load in the browser, I can do

```js
import "../node_modules/foo/bar.js";
const bar = new Bar({a: "a"});
```

and it works, but when bundling in Parcel it needs to be changed to

```js
import * as Bar from "../node_modules/foo/bar.js";
const bar = new Bar({a: "a"});
```

Is there a way to have a unified import that will work in both cases?